# Dresser drawers getting stuck

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture

I've got a dresser whose drawers get stuck and won't open. Nothing is blocking them, they just seem to get stuck on the runners. None of the runners seem loose or damaged, so I don't really know what's going on.

I found some sites that said to try and rub some wax on them, but this didn't work. I just used some paraffin wax, is there a better solution?

Should I try to sand them down?

I've attached some pictures of drawers and the runners.

EDIT:
None of the runners are loose, and the wax didn't work so I'll try sanding them this weekend and posting an update. Since none are loose, can I assume that they are still square?

[image: Closeup of one runner]
[image: There are two runners per drawer]
[image: Bottom of the drawer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the runners are tightly secured to the cabinet, and the screws holding the tracks on the bottom of the drawer are also tight.

If they are, then remove one and inspect the sliding surfaces for any obstruction, and any shiny spot. A shiny spot is a rubbing spot. Rub shiny spots with 80 grit sandpaper.

If you still have the problem, with this runner still removed, try sliding the drawer with just the other one installed. If it sticks, then remove that runner and check it out like above.

If this has not solved the problem, check the runners and tracks for squareness. You can also measure the distance between the center of the runners, front and back, and the center of the tracks, front and back to determine if one of them needs moving slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Along with @getterdun suggestions try rubbing a candle on the tracks. The wax will lubricate the tracks. Trial fit the drawers in another location. It may fit better in one location than another.